# Use GNU parallel to run script with different input arguments

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have a script called `step1.sh`, and I pass one input parameter to the script ($1).
I can run the script like this if I want the input to be 300.1

```
./step1.sh 300.1
```

I want to run this script 200 times, with 200 different inputs (they are random numbers, not a logical list of numbers). And I only want 4 scripts to run in parallel at a time.

Can someone help me write a command I can run in Ubuntu terminal to achieve this?

I am thinking I can create a .txt-file, `input_parameters.txt`, with the 200 different inputs.

```
300.1
290.12
250.2
250
174
250.1
```

And then something like:

```
cat input_parameters.txt | parallel -j 4 sh step1.sh
```

I am not well experienced with GNU parallel and struggle to find out which options to use. Can someone help me write a command?

Answer (score 1):

Yep this should work:

```
cat input_parameters.txt | parallel -j 4 sh step1.sh
```

Consider spending 20 minutes on reading chapter
1+2 https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014  Your command line will love you for it.